# Service httpd restart error

Tags: networking, centos, httpd, linux-networking, service

Why do i always get the error when ever i reset my httpd:

```
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Everytime i have to use `sudo fuser -k -n tcp 80`(i dunt know what it does) and then it works..
How can i solve this issue permanently?

using CentOS 6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) look for open files which might use port 80

```
lsof -i :80
```

2) check your apache.conf / httpd.conf  for the directive  `Listen`

3) Check the /var/log/httpd/error.log